# Programmatic way to call go tools

Tags: go, go-toolchain

Is there a way to call the Go tools (like `go build`) programmatically from within another Go program with a library call and to get more structured output compared to the text output from the command line invocation?

Comment: I don't think you can get more then what the help shows you. You can call it using the `os/exec` package.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to run build programmatically you can also use the `os/exec` package.

```
func runBuild() {
    cmd := exec.Command("go", "build", "./main.go")
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

You can pass other flags too. E.g: the buildmode flag

```
cmd := exec.Command("go", "build", "-buildmode=plugin", "./main.go")
```

Reference: https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/

Answer (score -2):

Within another go program it is possible to execute console commands using the `os/exec` package like so:

```
func main (){
   cmd := exec.Command("go run lib/main.go")
   if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil{
       log.Fatal(err)
   }
}
```

I don't see this being very useful though.

Comment: The first argument to exec.Command is the name of the program.  The name of the program is `go`, not `go run lib/main.go`.  See the @Stephen's answer for correct way to run the go command.